# Copied .ass Subtitle Has Font Size Changed

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, subtitle

This is happening when doing an mkv to mkv conversion, with a simple -c:s copy, and whilst the font style, and position are the same, the size ends up being bigger. I'm also playing it with VLC ,if that matters.

Here're the sub settings:
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub r8942
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayDepth: 0
YCbCr Matrix: TV.601
PlayResX: 708
PlayResY: 480
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default
Video AR Mode: 4
Video AR Value: 1.333333
Video Zoom Percent: 1.000000
Video Position: 35410

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Funimitation,28,&H00FFFFFF,&H0300FFFF,&H00000000,&H02000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,1,0,1,2,0,2,40,40,25,1
Style: Lyrics JPN,Faxfont Tone,40,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H501D0032,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,0,0,8,0,0,10,0
Style: Lyrics ENG,Faxfont Tone,36,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H501D0032,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,6,0
Style: Title,Faxfont Tone,55,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H28616161,&H28E0E0E0,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,0.5,0.1,2,10,10,20,1
Style: Credits ENG,Faxfont Tone,42,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H501D0032,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,0,0,8,0,0,0,0

And here's a sub example:
[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:17.95,0:00:20.79,Credits ENG,,0,0,0,,{\blur0.6\c&HFFF3ED&\fscx60\fscy76\pos(102.882,73)}Planning

If I export the sub from the converted file, all of the settings are the same.

Is there any way to stop the size from changing?

Thanks

Tried: -c:s copy
Expected: Complete copy.
Resulted: Not a complete copy -- the font size was bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add the attachments with -map 0:t.